# ASN1 viewer with grammar support?

Tags: windows, viewer, data-storage, asn.1

Can someone refer me a *free* ASN.1 viewer for windows which would also support to load the grammar file (.asn) to format the output.

I'm using the free version ASN1VE, which is fine, but I'd have to pay to be able to load the grammar.

Thanks!

f.